# Why are cookies not being sent?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, cookies

I'm a rookie MERN stack developer. In this project, I'm using ReactJS library for frontend and Express as backend framework.

I'm trying to store Jsonwebtoken in cookies after logging in but it seems like the cookies are not there.

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://orign-project-backend.herokuapp.com/user/verify', {withCredentials: true})
    .then((res) => {
        setCurrentUser(res.user)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
},[])
```

This is a useEffect hook I use on the main route to prevent user's state from disappearing everytime they refresh the page. It sends a GET request to the backend server then the backend server is supposed to verify jwt, which is stored in cookies and send back the decoded jwt.

```
  app.get("/user/verify",function(req,res){
    (jwt.verify(req.cookies.token,key.secretOrKey,(err,decodedToken) =>{
      if (err) res.status(404).json(req.cookies)
      else {res.json(decodedToken)};
    }));
  })
  app.post("/user/login",function(req,res){
  let loggedUser = new User({
    user: req.body.user,
    password: req.body.password
  })
  let validateLogin = inputValidator(loggedUser,false);
  if (!validateLogin.isValid) res.status(404).json(validateLogin.error);
  else{
  User.findOne({user: loggedUser.user},(err,userFound) => {
      if (err) res.status(404).json({inputError: "Some error occured!"});
      if (!userFound) res.status(404).json({inputNotFound:"Invalid Username or Password"});
      else {
        bcrypt.compare(loggedUser.password,userFound.password)
        .then((isMatch) => {
          if (isMatch){
            console.log(userFound._id)
            const payload = {
              user: userFound.user,
              id: userFound._id
            };
            jwt.sign(payload,key.secretOrKey,{expiresIn: 300000},(err,token) => {
              if (err) res.status(404).json({cannotSign:"error when signing jwt"})
              else  {
                res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true,maxAge: 360000 });
                res.json({token})
              }
            })
          }
          else res.status(404).json({inputNotFound:"Invalid Username or Password"})
        })
      }
    })}
  })
```

This is code for login API and user verification API (**backend is deployed on heroku but frontend is run on localhost**)

```
const corsOptions = {
origin: "http://localhost:3000",
credentials: true}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

This is my cors configuration.

**The problem** is that everytime I tried refreshing the page after logging in, the server always send an error saying token is invalid. Then I found out that the cookies are not being sent at all, possibly since logging in even though I did include `{withCredentials: true}` on every POST and GET request. (tried sending cookies back as json if an error occurs, turns out it's empty)

EDIT: Login API and User verification API work fine, cookies are sent normally (tested in Postman)

I'm really sorry if this question is not concise or not clear, this is my second time asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers work differently than Postman (and other tools) when setting cookies from different ports for security reasons. The browser won't honor the cookie request, even though you have no CORS errors because you probably have to meet certain security protocols.

I see your cookie code doesn't have a `Secure` param. Chrome, for instance, requires cookies to be set to secure = true and sameSite = "none" when they are being deployed by a server on a different port than the FE. They also need to be running on an HTTPS connection (not HTTP).

If you're getting this error in Chrome, make sure that all three of those are set correctly.